# request.user is not letting me make changes to the current user?

Tags: django, django-views

In my view function, I'm trying to make 2 modifications to the current user; consider him a premium subscriber by marking model field `is_premium_subscriber` as True and adding him to a group named `Premium Agents`.

However the changes don't seem to be registering in my views.py!  Here is my code:

```
def payment_response(request):
    new_charge = PremiumSubscriptionCharge()

    if request.method == "POST":
        ... Some code here

    try:

        ... lots of code here

        new_charge.agent = request.user  # This line is working fine, meaning request.user is properly assigned to the current user

        request.user.is_premium_subscriber = True  # This is not working, is_premium_subscriber is still false after the request

        premium_agent_group = Group.objects.get(name='Premium Agents')
        premium_agent_group.user_set.add(request.user)  # This is not working either, the current user does not get added to the group.

        request.user.save()  # I don't know if this is necessary, but I put it here just in case.


    except stripe.error.CardError as ce:
        ... some code

    else:
        ... some code
```

My user model for reference.  I created a custom User model by inheriting AbstractUser... could this have caused the issue?

```
class Agent(AbstractUser):
    is_premium_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

---

Full views function:

```
def payment_response(request):
    new_charge = PremiumSubscriptionCharge()

    if request.method == "POST":
        token = request.POST.get("stripeToken")

    try:

        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = request.user.email,
            source = token,
        )
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount = 1500,
            currency = 'cad',
            customer = customer.id,
            description = "Agent Premium Subscription"
        )

        subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=customer.id,
            items=[
                {
                    "plan": "premiumagent",
                },
            ],
        )


        new_charge.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
        new_charge.agent = request.user
        new_charge.customer = charge.customer
        new_charge.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id
        request.user.is_premium_subscriber = True
        premium_agent_group = Group.objects.get(name='Premium Agents')
        premium_agent_group.user_set.add(request.user)
        request.user.save()


    except stripe.error.CardError as ce:
        return False, ce

    else:
        new_charge.save()
        return redirect("payment_success")
```

Comment: The `request.user.save()` **is** necessary. The code you have posted should work. Perhaps the changes could be rolled back if you hit an exception.

Comment: Have you [enabled your custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) by setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.Agent'` in your settings?

Comment: You should inspect what `request.user` yields in your view...

Comment: @Alasdair.  Yes I have it as `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Agent'` in my settings.py.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `new_charge.agent = request.user` - new_charge.agent has a foreignkey relationship with my User (Agent) model, and request.user in this case is linking properly.  This tells me request.user is correctly attached to the currently logged in user.

Comment: @Valachio this tells you nothing until you save `new_charge`, and I can't see any mention of `new_charge.save()` in your code.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I posted the full views function.  After the request completes, my admin page shows that the newly added new_charge.agent indeed has the correct Agent attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was working on something else, came back to it, and now it is working.  What the.  Thank you to those who commented.